# Parsing internationl address with python package

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm trying to parse international address by using python package,Do we have any package available ?

I am looking for package, it should work for all the countries addresses.I know we have 'usaddress' package, but its working for USA addresses only.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [PyPostal](https://github.com/openvenues/pypostal).

To install the Python library, just run:

```
pip install postal
```

See the instructions from the GitHub page and make sure to install the pre-requisites before installing the package.